# What are the steps to minimise making requests for user data with the Facebook Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook

I have been going through the [tutorials on using the Facebook Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/personalize).

I noticed that it makes the asynchronous request to get the info whenever the `onCreateView` is called:

`Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // Get the user's data
        makeMeRequest(session);
    }`

So whenever a configuration change is made (orientation) or it create the fragment navigating back from another activity it makes the request.

I think that this is a waste of network usage and time as all I need is the profile picture, name and email. These values do not usually change very frequently.

I think one way is to make the request once each time an authenticated user opens the app. Then cache the data or use `SharedPreferences` from that point onwards.

I am storing one image and two text fields.

How should I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use simple boolean flag saved in shared preferences to check whether you actually downloaded user facebook data? Set this flag to true after finished download and set to false when user is leaving your app.

Answer (score 0):

I used to just render the cached data in the OnCreateView. Why are you making that request in the OnCreateView ?
I think not making that request will not cause any problems!